# Integration of $\int_0^{\infty } \frac{\sin (q r) \left(A+B+M \left(q^2 r^2-2\right)\right)+q r (-A-B+2 M) \cos (q r)}{2 \pi ^2 q r^3} \, dq$

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence

I am having to perform the following integral,
$$\int_0^{\infty } \frac{\sin (q r) \left(A+B+M \left(q^2 r^2-2\right)\right)+q r (-A-B+2 M)
   \cos (q r)}{2 \pi ^2 q r^3} \, dq$$
here, $A, B, M\in\mathbb{C}$ and $r>0$ and $r$ is a real number.
Is it possible to do the integration analytically? Does the integral converge? Can the integral be solved by going into complex plane and choosing a suitable contour? Can the integral be expressed as combination of Dirac Delta distributions.

Comment: Integration of the second term in the numerator looks eerily like a definition of Dirac delta function. Can the whole thing be written as Dirac deltas?

Comment: It seems that the integral of the from $$\int_0^\infty \frac{a\sin(x)-ax\cos(x)+bx^2\sin(x)}{x} dx$$ [does not converge](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+from+0+to+infinity+a+sin%28x%29%2Fx-++a+cos%28x%29%2Bb+xsin%28x%29+dx) in general.

Comment: The improper integral diverges. If we drop $C \sin(r q)/q$, for which $\int_0^A$ has a finite limit, we're left with $C_1 q \sin r q + C_2 \cos r q$, for which $\int_0^A$ doesn't have a limit. The distributional limit exists:
$$\int_0^A \cos r q \, dq =
\frac {\sin A r} r \, \xrightarrow {\mathcal D} \,
\pi \delta(r), \\
\int_0^A q \sin r q \, dq \, \xrightarrow {\mathcal D} \,
-\pi \delta'(r)$$
(all for $A \to \infty$).